# Is it possible to turn on HTML encoding by default in ASP.NET 4?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0, html-encode

In ASP.NET 4, we can use the new `<%: ... %>` operator to output HTML encoded strings. Is it possible to configure **ASP.NET 4** (in web.config) so that the `<%= ... %>` operator will also HTML encode strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, fortunately.

If you configure it this way, your developers will get into the habit of using `<%= ... %>` and not encoding.

If they subsequently work on a different (normal) project, they will end up forgetting to encode their output.

[ASP.Net Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) does default to HTML encoding, because it doesn't have this issue.
(There is no Razor code you can switch to that won't encode by default)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I don't like this new `<%:` syntax. I rather use `<%= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(` because it is much more explicit.

Besides this, it gives a false sense of security, because it only does HTML encoding. Look at this snippet for instance:

```
function myJavaScriptFunction()
{
    var message = '<%: Person.LastComment %>';
    alert(message);
}
```

It is not save, because it doesn't use the proper encoding.  The following is safe:

```
function myJavaScriptFunction()
{
    var message = '<%: AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(Person.LastComment) %>';
    alert(message);
}
```

Much more explicit.

Comment: +1 for a fair a making a good point, but not exactly an answer to the question!